# Can malloc() be used to define the size of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

Here consider the following sample of code:

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

Can this code be used to define an array a containing n integers?

Comment: It can be used to make a pointer to point to a memory capable of containing `n` integers. That's it. There is no notion of arrays in this code.

Comment: the above line of code doesnt define an array, then? But I can use an array a in my program with no declaration otherwise

Comment: No, `int *a` does not define an array, no matter how you initialize it.  Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: No, @Cherubim, there is no pointer arithmetic here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I thought here `a[i]` would be the same as `a + i`. can you please explain where I'm mistaken.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  What you've done here is allocated enough memory for `n` values of type `int` and pointed `a` to the beginning of the allocated buffer.  Because `a` is of type `int*`, and because you can index through pointers (e.g. `a[1]` interprets the second `sizeof(int)` bytes as an `int`), you can treat it much like the array you describe; but it doesn't "know" its number of elements, `a`'s not const so you could move it and it would no longer point to the base of the array, and if you point, say, a `char*` at the same buffer it can just as well interpret the data as `char`s

Comment: Code be used to _allocate space_ for `n` `int`.  That does not define nor declare an _array_.

Comment: You can use array syntax with a pointer: `a[i]` will work as long as `i` is less than `n`.

Comment: @Cherubim `a[i]` is the same as `*(a+i)`

Comment: oops @user3386109 , my bad I meant it to be `*(a + i)`

Comment: @Cherubim, there is no array indexing here, either.  Even if there were, array indexing is not usually characterized as "pointer arithmetic", the equivalence you refer to (which is actually `a[i]` being equivalent to `*(a + i)`) notwithstanding.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I'd say that the `malloc` call, if it succeeds, creates an anonymous array object (assuming `n > 0`). If that weren't the case, then the expression `a[0]` or `a+0` would be invalid.

Comment: @KeithThompsin Not only anonymous but also a typeless. Which is making it hardly being an array in the C terminology.

Comment: It's as typeless as the automatic storage for any variable, though. So I fail to see why a distinction should be made here.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the standard describes the space allocated by `malloc` as an array.

Comment: @KeithThompson whether `a[0]` or `a+0` are valid doesn't have a bearing on whether `a` points to (or is) an array. I think it would be somewhat more accurate to say that the `malloc` call returns a space that can be used to store an array. But that does not mean that this space _is_ an array.

Comment: @davmac: Of course `a` isn't an array. `a` is a pointer object. It doesn't point to an array object, it points to the initial element of an array object. `malloc` doesn't return "space", it returns a pointer value. The section of the standard that I cited doesn't imply that there's an array object, but if there weren't, then `a[0]` would not be a valid expression (evaluating it would have undefined behavior). But N1570 7.22.3p1 says that the returned pointer, after assignment, may be "used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated".

Comment: @KeithThompson as per my comment on your answer below, `a[0]` is a valid expression when `a` points at a single object (i.e. not an array) due to N1570 6.5.6p7: _For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type_. `malloc` returns a pointer to an object, yes - which is a "region of allocated storage" (standard speak), or "space" (layman speak). Ok, I said "space" instead of "pointer to space". That's not the point at hand.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.22.3p1: "The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated)." If the pointer can be used to access an array object, then the array object must exist.

Answer (score 7):

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

> Can this code be used to define an array a containing n integers?

That depends on what you mean by "define an array".

A declaration like:

```
int arr[10];
```

defines a named array object.  Your pointer declaration and initialization does not.

However, the `malloc` call (*if* it succeeds and returns a non-`NULL` result, and *if* `n > 0`) will create an anonymous array object at run time.

But it does not "define an array `a`".  `a` is the name of a *pointer* object. Given that the `malloc` call succeeds, `a` will point to the initial element of an array object, but it is not itself an array.

Note that, since the array object is anonymous, there's nothing to which you can apply `sizeof`, and no way to retrieve the size of the array object from the pointer. If you need to know how big the array is, you'll need to keep track of it yourself.

(Some of the comments suggest that the `malloc` call allocates memory that can hold `n` integer objects, but not an array. If that were the case, then you wouldn't be able to access the elements of the created array object. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.6p8 for the definition of pointer addition, and 7.22.3p1 for the description of how a `malloc` call can create an accessible array.)

Comment: p7: _For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type._ This allows the case of `i == 0` if `a` is _not_ an array; `a[0]` is valid if `a` points to an object that is not an array.

Comment: @davmac: Updated with a citation of the standard's description of how the pointer returned by `malloc` can be used to access an array.

Comment: Your answer still says "the indexing expression `a[i]`, where `(i >= 0 && i < n)`, is valid only if the pointer `a` points to an element of an array object" which, as I've indicated, is not correct.

Comment: @davmac: Updated.

Answer (score 5):

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

Assuming `malloc()` call succeeds, you can use the pointer `a` *like* an array using the array notation (e.g. `a[0] = 5;`). But `a` is not an array itself; it's just a pointer to an `int` (and it may be a block of memory which can store multiple `int`s).

Your comment

> But I can use an array a in my program with no declaration otherwise

suggests this is what you are mainly asking about.

In C language,

```
p[i] == *(p + i) == *(i + p) == i[p]
```

as long as one of `i` or `p` is of pointer type (`p` can an array as well -- as it'd be converted into a pointer in any expression). Hence, you'd able to index `a` like you'd access an array. But `a` is actually a pointer.

Comment: And even the dynamically allocated object -- as distinct from the pointer to it -- is not an array.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That is exactly what `malloc()` does.

The important distinction is that

```
int array[10];
```

declares `array` as an array object with enough room for 10 integers. In contrast, the following:

```
int *pointer;
```

declares `pointer` as a single pointer object.

It is important to distiguinsh that one of them is a pointer and that the other as an actual array, and that arrays and pointers are closely related but are different things. However, saying that there is no array in the following is also incorrect:

```
pointer = malloc(sizeof (int) * 10);
```

Because what this piece of code does is precisely to allocate an array object with room for 10 integers. The pointer `pointer` contains the address of the first element of that array.<sup>(C99 draft, section 7.20.3 "Memory management functions")</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Interpreting your question very literally, the answer is No: To "define an array" means something quite specific; an array definition looks something like:

```
int a[10];
```

Whereas what you have posted is a memory allocation. It allocates a space suitable for holding an array of 10 `int` values, and stores a pointer to the first element within this space - but it doesn't *define* an array; it *allocates* one.

With that said, you can use the *array element access* operator, `[]`, in either case. For instance the following code snippets are legal:

```
int a[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) a[i] = 0;
```

and

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = 0;
```

There is a subtle difference between what they do however. The first defines an array, and sets all its elements to 0. The second allocates storage which can hold an equivalently-typed array value, and uses it for this purpose by initialising each element to 0.

It is worth pointing out that the second example does not check for an allocation error, which is generally considered bad practice. Also, it constitutes a potential memory leak if the allocated storage is not later freed.

Comment: so do i need to define an array at the given memory allocation to avoid segmentation fault?

Comment: @kartikeykant18 you mean "define an array at the given memory *location*" I think; but no. There is no way to define an array at a specific memory location (in standard C, that I know of). But, as I have shown, you can allocate space for an array and use it. Be aware that "define" has a special meaning here.

Comment: @kartikeykant18, you *cannot* define an array at the address of a dynamic memory allocation.  But that has nothing to do with segmentation faults.  You can store data in the dynamically allocated space just fine, as long as you stay within its bounds.

Answer (score 0):

In the language the Standard was written to describe (as distinct from the language that would be described by a pedantic literal reading of it), the intention was that malloc(n) would return a pointer that would, if cast to a `T*`, could be treated as a pointer to the first element of a `T[n/sizeof T*]`.  Per N1570 7.22.3:

> The
>       pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to
>       a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used
>       to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space
>       is explicitly deallocated).

The definition of pointer addition and subtraction, however, do not speak of acting upon pointers that are "suitably aligned" to allow access to arrays of objects, but rather speak of pointers to elements of actual array objects.  If a program accesses space for 20 `int` objects, I don't think the Standard does actually says that the resulting pointer would behave in all respects as though it were a pointer to element [0] of an `int[20]`, as distinct from e.g. a pointer to element [0][0] of an `int[4][5]`.  An implementation would have to be really obtuse not to allow it to be used as either, of course, but I don't think the Standard actually requires such treatment.