# Hackerrank circular array rotation segmentation faults

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My following code sucessfully runs in sample input but gives segmentation faults in  13 test cases.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){
    int n; 
    int k; 
    int q; 
    int index[q];
    scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&k,&q);
    int *a = (malloc(sizeof(int) * n));
    for(int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++){
       scanf("%d",&a[a_i]);
    }
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++){
        int m; 
        scanf("%d",&m);
        index[a0] = m;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
        int ap = a[n-2];       

        for(int p=1; p<n-1; p++){
            a[p] = a[p-1];
        }
        a[0] = a[n-1];
        a[n-1] = ap;      


    }
    for(int j=0; j<q;j++){
        printf("%d\n", a[index[j]]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to find where the segmentation fault is. Also check out this:[where I asked about declaring a as a pointer using malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41512872/can-malloc-be-used-to-define-the-size-of-an-array/41513426#41513426)

There might have been chances that using malloc() to declare a would have lead to segmentation faults since it does not check for allocation error, but even when i defined a as an array the problem still remained.

Comment: Buy one of the inputs where it seg faults (it should be 5 hackos) and use `gdb`.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting: `int q;  int index[q];`

Comment: no @kartikeykant18 you cannot... and moreover here q is uninitialized.

Comment: can malloc() be used for this purpose? for variable size?

Comment: yes that's the reason why dynamic memory allocation is used :)

Comment: Does `int *a(malloc(sizeof(int) * n));` compile?

Comment: @WeatherVane I was wondering the same thing. AFAIK, you can't initialize a variable in C like this, but C++ would require a cast.

Comment: it was a typo sorry, it should be int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n), i am using C and it did create a compilation error

Comment: How can you make a typo like that? You would copy/paste **if** that is really your program. But to my point: when `n < 2` the line `int ap = a[n-2];` will give trouble.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah, i think this is the reason of segmentaion faults in few test cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

q is not initialized, but is used as the argument to the declaration of an array.

You should use malloc to allocate the index array, after reading the value of q.